# It's hard to create files/folders at the root of the VS Code workspace. Is it possible to add more space to the bottom of the Explorer View?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a lot of folders and things in my python folder. How do I make it so that there is a fixed amount of space at the bottom of the Explorer View's treelist, even if it would cause overflow when there otherwise wouldn't be, creating a scrollbar? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUHj4.png).

Comment: @noob Oh, you don't even need blank space for that! You can just click the "New folder" button at the top. Or you can right-click on the scroll bar, at least on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04). I guess this is an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: @wjandrea that makes sense, but I can still see where the asker is coming from, because those buttons will create something at the same/related level as whatever is currently selected. So if you want to create something at the "root" level, it's a bit of a pain in the bum and also a little bit unintuitive.

Comment: @starball Oh, I didn't realize the buttons do that. I guess I don't use them very much. But right-clicking on the scroll bar always goes to the root level.

Comment: @wjandrea that's a strange behaviour. but 1) it's a little inconvenient to use- it opens up a context menu 2) I'm tempted to wonder if that itself is a bug, since anything previously just selected in a nested folder stays highlighted as if it were still selected. anyhow, I've found what I think is the answer to this question and posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, this is supposed to already be part of vanilla VS Code. See [Test: top level resource creation in explorer #79800](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79800), which was created as the solution to issue tickets like [Difficult to create folder in left panel file view if the open folder only contains folder #1043](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1043) (pretty much exactly the problem you are describing). I guess that part of that change regressed. I've raised the regression in an issue ticket at [The `additionalScrollHeight` part of #79800 seems to have regressed #190092](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190092). My issue ticket is actually probably a duplicate of [File list margin is gone in 1.81 #189809](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189809), which would indicate that this is a very recent regression (version 1.81 of VS Code), likely caused by [Pull Request #178627](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/178627). The fix for the issue was made in [commit `a0377f0`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a0377f0c51dbb2d3188565cdf35e89929f864e65), which is scheduled for release in the August 2023 release of VS Code.

As for what your root goal is- to create files or folders at the root of the workspace folder, yeah, I feel your pain. The default behaviour of the buttons at the top of the Explorer View create things at the same level of the currently selected file (if a file is selected), or under the currently selected directory (if a directory is selected). On the bright side, the other changes made and which were under test in [#79800](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/79800) including allowing you to press <kbd>esc</kbd> to unfocus list items and put focus on the listing as a whole (which then allows you to use the new file/folder action buttons at the top of the Explorer View to create a file/folder at the root of the tree) still works, so you can use that as a workaround for now.

There's also a related issue ticket: ["New file" / "New folder" on file context menu #83693](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83693) where it's closed as not planned, and preferred for implementation via extensions, where in that thread, [`wenfangdu.faster-new`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wenfangdu.faster-new) is listed as one such extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.